# I want to use Kubernetes but cannot upload image to dockerhub

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a Spring Boot application which the management is not easy about having the image be put on dockerhub, so I would like to deploy the image onto kubectl (from my local machine) but so far I have failed. I have researched about it alot and found basically nothing

Comment: Any error message? Or where exactly do you fail?

Comment: At KubeSail it tried to run Spring Boot, and prints the logo and then nothing, stop and tries to restart. it does this again and again. I am trying to go for Amazon kubernetes now, Would you have any idea of how to setup spring boot app on amazon please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a local docker registry, push your image to that and then deploy it via kubectl

If you are using EKS the easiest way is to push your image ECR and then deploy. Can you show us the deployment.yaml?

Please make sure it contains your image in this format:
ACCOUNT.dkr.ecr.REGION.amazonaws.com/imagename:tag

Comment: I found this link I am following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53587996/how-to-push-and-deploy-local-image-to-kubernetes

Comment: I am using KubeSail and when I run this command `kubectl create -f deployment.yaml`, it gives this back and creates an instance on the server `deployment.apps/spring-demo created`
but on the server I get this error `trying and failing to pull image","reason":"BadRequest","code":400}`

Comment: Are you sure have the correct image

Comment: My Pods started when i had a larger plan on aws but on free tier with 1 node I get this
` Warning  FailedScheduling  88s (x7 over 10m)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient pods.`

Comment: How many replicas does your deployment yaml have? what do you get when you run 'kubectl get nodes'

Comment: `apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: spring-demo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: spring-demo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: spring-demo
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: spring-demo-app
          image: saeedarcana/spring-demo
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8085`

Comment: Yeah as I said your image should be like this:

Comment: Please make sure it contains your image in this format: ACCOUNT.dkr.ecr.REGION.amazonaws.com/imagename:tag

Comment: you need to push it to ecr if you want it private, as it is I can see it `docker pull saeedarcana/spring-demo`

Comment: At this point I just want to learn kubernetes n see my service online. Lets keep the private part on low priority

Comment: Your answer to number of nodes is 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100671/discussion-between-r-doolan-and-eshan-i).

Comment: You are not available in chat R.

Answer (score 0):

[Kubernetes in Docker](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/) is a new tool that makes it much easier to work with **Kubernetes locally**. I work daily with Kubernetes and have recently started to use this solution, it works great.

Comment: Now I've moved to AWS EKS.